# How would i make a small script from Mel that controls mesh is selectable or not, and i can i do a same thing in python?

Tags: maya, mel

I trying to make a script using Mel that uses setObjectPickMask so tried doing this code

```
if (ObjectPickMask "Surface" == true)
{
setObjectPickMask "Surface" false;
updateObjectSelectionMasks;
updateComponentSelectionMasks;
dR_selTypeChanged("");
    
}

else if (ObjectPickMask "Surface" == false)
{
setObjectPickMask "Surface" true;
updateObjectSelectionMasks;
updateComponentSelectionMasks;
dR_selTypeChanged("");

}
```

It didnt work well i never wrote a Mel before. so basically i am trying to do is make a script that makes Mesh Selectable and non Selectable just like the button in the status line but in script form.

Please share your thoughts how can i achieve this and is this possible doing in python?

Answer (score 0):

The following might do what you are after.

The if statement will test the condition when you enable or disable the surface button from the pick menu. [image] Here, `if` will query it and return a `true` or `false`.

I see that you have echoed the other statements, so I just put them back in.

Also, with MEL, you always need to use backticks when capturing the return value of a command in a variable or when testing a command's output in a conditional.

**Notice** the backticks in the test of the `if statement`.

```
if (`selectType -query -nurbsSurface` == true)
    {
        setObjectPickMask "Surface" false;
        updateObjectSelectionMasks;
        updateComponentSelectionMasks;
        dR_selTypeChanged("");
    }
else
    {        
        setObjectPickMask "Surface" true;
        updateObjectSelectionMasks;
        updateComponentSelectionMasks;
        dR_selTypeChanged("");    
    }
```